# Phoenix: How to store state shared across sockets in a channel?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an app where 2 people chat. But before they chat, BOTH parties have to press "accept"

on the front end I have a button that calls this function:

```
function acceptMatch() {
  channel.push("accept_match", {
    "matched_client_email": matchedClientEmail,
  });
}
```

in my phoenix channel I have this (which is incomplete because I'm not sure what to do):

```
  def handle_in("accept_match", %{ "matched_client_email" => matched_client_email }, socket) do
    Logger.info "accept_match"
    ...
    ############################### here ####################################
    match_accepted = true # <-- I want to be able to find out if the other person has pressed "accept" as well
    case match_accepted do
      true ->
        ...
        {:noreply, socket}
      _ ->
        {:noreply, socket}
    end
  end
```

I looked into `Agent`, but that seems to be tied to a PID, which I wouldn't be able to easily pass around to different sockets. I'm trying to look for a common storage (other than a database) between all connections that I can save to / query. This way if party A presses accept, I can ask the storage "did party B accept?"

=== UPDATE ===

When I try using a named Agent I get this:

```
iex(11)> myfunc = fn -> %{} end
#Function<20.52032458/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex(12)> Agent.start_link(myfunc, name: "Cool")
** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: {"Cool", []}
    (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:544: GenServer.do_start/4
iex(12)>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it seems that you might pass to each new connection in `connect` in your `user_socket` this particular PID or name of the Agent and it should solve this case. You only need one Agent, so you can name it, eg.

```
Agent.start_link(your_func, name: :myagent)
```

and later get from it

```
Agent.get(:myagent, your_get_func)
```

Also you can consider to use [Registry](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Registry.html), which is from Elixir 1.4 in standard library.

This agent can be in `lib` and you can just add it in the `<app_name>.ex` file as a single worker and supervise it with dedicated Supervisor if needed.

Comment: ooo cool! when I tried doing it I get an error... updated my question with the error

Comment: Yes, sorry. I updated my answer. Name must meet requirements in https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-name-registration